# How to identify the values that do not exist in JSON file in Oracle column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle table that has `JSON` column that store one or more values. I would like to know if there is a way to check if the set of values I pass to the query exists in that column. The values that do not exist, should return in a query result. Below is the example.

This is `history` table data row example.

```
HISTID  REFID   CREATUSERID CREATDT
3       25      mjhons      2021-06-25 00:06:09
```

This is my `reference` table data row example.

```
REFID   REFNAME     PREDECESSOR
25      MMK06789    []
26      MMK06790    []
27      GKO67821    ["MMK06789","MMK06790"]
```

In the example above you can see sample of data from both tables `history` and `reference`. The query that will be checking for the `PREDECESSOR` is below.

```
SELECT R.REFNAME 
FROM HISTORY H JOIN REFERENCE R ON H.REFID = R.REFID 
WHERE H.CREATDT >= TRUNC(sysdate) AND R.REFNAME IN ('MMK06789', 'MMK06790')
```

The query above will join records from two tables and only return records where `CREATDT` is greater or equal than current date and if `REFNAME` exists in `history` table.

However, I need result set to check if `PREDECESSOR` values `('MMK06789', 'MMK06790')` exist in the `history` table and the `CREATDT` is greater or equal than current date and return the `PREDECESSOR` value that does not exist in the `history` table. In this case for the data provided above query should return `MMK06790`. That value is not in the `history` table. I was looking into  `JSON_TABLE` function but couldn't figure out the way to return the record that doesn't exist. If anyone knows how to get this to work please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if values of "PREDECESSOR" are known to you then INSTR() function can be used to check whether the value is present in the table or not. if not then INSTR() will return 0.